# What is a cross-origin request and how do I get around them?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, express, redis

I've been trying to follow along with this video about making a UserManager App with Backbone.js, Node.js, Redis, Express, Nohm, Ajax, and a ton new terms that I'm still getting used to.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk

However the link in the video takes me to a nearly blank page and the Chrome console gives the message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users. The request was      
redirected to 'https://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users', which is disallowed for 
cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the "Ajax prefilter" variable in the index.html file. Does everyone get this error? Why can't I see the app that is supposed to show up on this page?

Comment: change the url to https and see if it works.

Comment: That gives an error, "this page cannot be displayed". I'm able to go to the site from the youtube video in Internet Explorer, but Chrome gives this error.